# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to get my head around groovy scripting to make some changes to a jenkins pipeline and I keep getting this error:

`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: credentials for class:`

I have tried declaring the variable with `def` but I still get the exception, eclipse does not recognise that the property exists.

What am I doing wrong?!

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy

package common.pipeline

import common.pipeline.Credentials

Credentials credentials = new Credentials()

def withCredentials(steps) {
    credentials.productionPipeline(steps)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This script will be compiled by groovy into a Script class with the field definition inside the `run` method, and with another method `withCredentials` that is trying to access the field (kinda like this):

```
import common.pipeline.Credentials

class Script1 extends Script {

    def withCredentials(steps) {
        credentials.productionPipeline(steps)
    }

    def run(args) {
        Credentials credentials = new Credentials()
    }
}
```

As you can see, this won't work, as the credentials aren't at Field level in the class...

Groovy has an annotation to make this happen:

```
#!/usr/bin/groovy

package common.pipeline

import common.pipeline.Credentials
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field Credentials credentials = new Credentials()

def withCredentials(steps) {
    credentials.productionPipeline(steps)
}
```

Comment: Thats working thanks, is it better to define groovy as classes if using inside a pipeline? If I had done that would this mean I wouldnt have got the same issue?